# Workaround for xargs Argument list too long in grep

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, grep, xargs

For every line of a file I need to search if an string, containing regular expressions, is found in another file.

The problem is that the files are big, the first is 24MB and the second 115MB. I've tried first $(cat file1) as first argument of grep but it complains for the file size and then I'm trying now with xargs grep but is the same error

If I do a simple string search works

```
find . -name records.txt | xargs grep "999987^00086"
999987^00086^14743^00061^4
```

but then if a try to take all the file with cat as argument it fails

```
find . -name records.txt | xargs grep "$(records_tofix.txt)"
-bash: /usr/bin/xargs Argument list too long on grep
```

Comment: I would expect your code to print `bash: records_tofix.txt: command not found` instead

Comment: You'll have a much, *much* more efficient time of this if you can sort your files and do a single merge operation for set comparisons -- far less memory usage and time that way (after the sort is done, granted, but the sort only needs to be done *once* per file). See `comm` as the canonical UNIX tool for set arithmetic (unions, joins, and differences) on sorted input streams.

Comment: Also, note that `xargs` should only be used with `-0` or `-d $'\n'` arguments (the latter is a GNUism, but it's a necessary GNUism if you want files with one line per record to be unambiguously and correctly parsed).

Comment: ...without one of those arguments, `foo bar` on one line will be treated as two separate records, `foo` and `bar`; backslashes, quotes, &c. also get special (shell-like but not-quite-shell-compatible) treatment.

Comment: Anyhow, `find . -name records.txt -exec grep -f records_tofix.txt -- {} +` is your friend; no reason to use `xargs` at all.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `-f` option:

```
grep -f records_tofix.txt
```

The file should contain the patterns each on its own line.

`find` can execute commands directly, no reason to call `xargs`. The `+` syntax of `-exec` doesn't call the command for each value separately, but fills the whole command line similarly to `xargs`:

```
find . -name records.txt -exec grep -f records_tofix.txt -- {} +
```